# How to set role when register a new user using strapi?

Tags: strapi

I'm try register an user and i would like to know how can i set role as Administrator.
I tried

```
user: {
  username: "elialber",
  email: "falecom@elialber.com.br",
  password: "123456789",
  role: ???
}
```

I'm using Angular5 and just api strapi

Answer (score 3):

In Strapi Admin:

Roles & Permissions -> Advances settings

Set the field **Default role for authenticated users** to "Administrator"

Answer (score 3):

step 1: Go to node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js
step 2: Go to on line 457(in my code)
step 3: Comment params.role=role.id; like (//params.role = role.id;)

and now you can pass role id like 1 or 2 or 3 as follow

```
{
    "blocked":false,
    "confirmed":true,
    "username":"aziz",
    "email":"musa@binarymarvels.com",
    "password":"musa01010",
    "role": 2
}



and now I receive a response like:
{
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MzQsImlhdCI6MTYwMjUzMzk0MSwiZXhwIjoxNjA1MTI1OTQxfQ.xM2tmP8PUcwABiW9lmxkjkmcmdmckMB8wlQ1YsBOQI",
    "user": {
        "id": 34,
        "username": "aziz",
        "email": "musa@binarymarvels.com",
        "provider": "local",
        "confirmed": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "role": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Public",
            "description": "Default role given to the unauthenticated user.",
            "type": "public"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-10-12T20:19:01.285Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-12T20:19:01.299Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: what about in production?

Comment: Terrible practice to modify node_modules, horrible.

Comment: modifying files directly in `node_modules` is generally considered bad practice. changes in node_modules are local to your environment, because node_modules is usually mentioned in `.gitignore`. so, what about your colleagues?also,  your file changes will get overwritten whenever you run an npm update or init command and the package you modified is updated along with it. that alone will  cause you a lot of headaches finding bugs

Comment: You can use npm patching to do this.. if there is no other solution to get role set then patching the package is a perfectly viable solution.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Answer (score 2):

One can write a custom endpoint to update user role, and add a corresponding controller action like below:

```
module.exports = {
    updateUserRole: async ctx => {
       return await strapi.services.auth.updateUserRole (ctx.request.body.user, 
                                                         ctx.request.body.roleType);

    }
};
```

auth service to update user role can be defined in api/auth/services/Auth.js  as below:

```
    module.exports = {

        updateUserRole: async (userid, roleType) => {
            const role = await strapi.query('role', 'users-permissions').findOne({ type:roleType }, []);
        if ( role ) {
            strapi.query('user',  'users-permissions').update({ id: userid }, { role: role.id });
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
user: {  
username: "elialber",   
email: "falecom@elialber.com.br",  
password: "123456789",   
role: {   
_id: "5afac95f0eabf75b64c6ef92" // role id that your app generate     
}}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I don't think this feature is available yet.

Comment: This maybe outdated. In strapi v4, internally the role id is not that hash, it's a simple number, and you can query by that id in users-permission and other internal collections.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L261

Add following code to root/plugins/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js in front of line 261

```
const roleType = params.role || settings.default_role
```

and change line 261

```
const role = hasAdmin === false ? root : await strapi.query('role', 'users-permissions').findOne({ type: roleType }, []);
```

post will like

```
{
    "username": "test user",
    "email": "qqqqqq@gmail.com",
    "password": "qqqqqq",
    "role": "boss" 
}
```

boss <--- role created from admin panel

worked on strapi v-3.0.0-alpha.25.2

Comment: I get this following error.
ReferenceError: roleType is not defined. what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solution also seen here:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-can-i-create-user-lifecycle-hooks-in-v4/13144/11

**How to modify the auth register controller to have control:**

```js
// /src/extensions/user-permissions/strapi-server.ts
export default function (plugin) {
  const registerController = plugin.controllers.auth.register;
  plugin.controllers.auth.register= async(ctx)=> {
    const body = ctx.request.body

    // do some modifications
    body.username = Math.random()

    await registerController(ctx)
  }

  return plugin;
}
```

**If you want to create a user with a role**, you can update the user after:

```js
// /src/extensions/user-permissions/strapi-server.ts
export default function (plugin) {
  const registerController = plugin.controllers.auth.register;
  plugin.controllers.auth.register= async(ctx)=> {
    const body = ctx.request.body

    // do some modifications
    body.username = Math.random()

    await registerController(ctx)

    // bind role
    const user = ctx.response._body.user;
    const updatedUser = await strapi.entityService.update("plugin::users-permissions.user", user.id, {
      data: {
        role: ctx.request.body.role
      },
      populate: {role: true}
    })

    user.role = updatedUser.role;
  }

  return plugin;
}
```

^^ with this you can pass the role in the request body as: `role: 4`